# Zend Controller Path with Sub Dirs

Tags: zend-framework, controller

I'm Using Zend Framework 1.11.x

I'm using the standard directory layout...
What I would like to do is have subdiretories in my controllers

```
controller
 --- MemberController.php
```

to be instead

```
controller
 --Member
    ---MemberController.php
```

When I add this directory structure, and then try to access the controller by doing something like this:

$this-url(array(controller=>'member'....)

it can not find the controller to create the url

How do i map this subdirectory? Do i have to put  each and every sub directory path in the application.ini?

If so Is there a way to do it generically so that I can just put (which i currently have) the base path in the application.ini?

thanks

Comment: So you want each controller to be in it's own subdirectory which has the same name as the controller itself? Or do you want all your controllers in a subdirectory called Member?

Answer (score 2):

if you're considering grouping controllers together, you might be better off using the standard zend modular structure:

In the bootstrap you add the directory for each module:

```
 $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

 $frontController->setControllerDirectory(array(
   'default' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers',
  'blog'    => APPLICATION_PATH . '/blog/controllers'
  'api'    =>   APPLICATION_PATH . '/api/controllers'
```

));

It's easy to manage and maintain, because the modules are self contained and separated from each another. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.modular.html

Answer (score 1):

Robert Basic has written about this:

[Grouping Zend Framework controllers in subdirectories](http://robertbasic.com/blog/grouping-zend-framework-controllers-in-subdirectories/)

Answer (score 1):

I've just been dealing with this very question but I ran into a few problems.  David Weinraub's answer leads to more information which had a comment then lead to page that had a credit that had the basic / simple way to doing this.

To avoid all that wrangling and to throw in some notes about Windows vs Linux, here's what I learned.

I want to simply organized some Admin controllers/actions in a sub-directory in my controllers directory such as this:

```
/application/controllers/
/application/controllers/admin/MyActionController.php
```

I didn't want to get involved with Modules.  This isn't a huge project that will have all kinds of modules, I just want to organize Admin files a little better.

First, my development machine is Win7 with Apache.  Our staging / Production machines are Linux (Debian-based).

The easiest solution is to simply create a custom route (I'll go over the route a little more below as to what it's doing for those unfamiliar with them).  I do this in the bootstrap as such:

```
->addRoute('AdminRoute',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/admin/:action/*', array('controller'=>'Admin_Index', 'action'=>'index'))
)
```

**NOTE**

- 'controller' => 'Admin_Index' uses capitol letters.  While this works in this example, I found that this was a misunderstanding of how to properly declare router controller names.  My next example will explain this.

I would then have this file in this directory:

```
/application/controllers/Admin/IndexController.php
```

and the Controller file would need the class name like this:

```
class Admin_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    ...
}
```

That's pretty straight forward.

Here's some issues I ran into.  Windows and Linux are known for having case-sensitive issues.  I believe Windows treats things as case-insensitive while Linux is case-sensitive.

Also, while my example above uses an Admin Controller class called "index", I actually had a Camel-Case class name such as "AdminIndexController.php".

This worked on Windows but caused problems on Linux.  I'm still not 100% sure where this occurs but went through and debug-output some of the Standard Router processes and discovered that the Custom Router setup needed a specific format when setting up routes.

I believe when declaring your controller in the standard router, you use the URL naming convention for parsing, instead of the ZF class name convention.  In other words, it would appear that the Router is case-insensitive so camel-casing wasn't properly telling the router where to find the router.  Instead, I needed to use dashes (I was already using underscores).

So, if you want to have a file named like this:

```
/application/controllers/Admin/FooIndexController.php
```

you should declare your custom router like this:

```
->addRoute('AdminRoute',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/admin/:action/*', array('controller'=>'admin_foo-index', 'action'=>'index'))
)
```

and your controller class name name will be:

```
class Admin_FooIndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    ...
}
```

**Custom router**

To explain the customer router, it basically says that for any URL that starts with:

```
"/admin/"
```

Use the defined controller and action.  I set the default controller to "admin_index" or "admin_foo-index" in the later example.

The part of the controller ":action/" is like a variable that tells ZF that something should be there are part of the URL.  However, we can give it a default value, if it's left blank.  Sort of like default arguments in programming functions.

In this case, I set 'action' => 'index'.  By default, it will use the 'index' Action, if none is declared.

If a value is given, it will use that value instead.  So, if someone uses the URL (assuming we're using the second example above):

```
/admin/users/
```

The router will use the controller/action

```
/application/controllers/Admin/FooIndexController.php
...
/* inside controller*/
function usersAction(){
    ...
}
```

Hopefully that helps a little.  I just went though this troubleshooting processes and this is what I discovered and solved the issues I was having.

Cheers!

Comment: One item of note, I had to use a capitol "A" for Admin in my controllers folder on Linux. "/controllers/Admin/"

Answer (score 0):

When you place a controller in a subdirectory, then you should change controller class name appended with `FOLDER_NAME` and `_`.

In your case the member controller class name would turn to

```
Member_MemberController
```

Then url to access this controller will be

```
SITE_PATH/Member_Member
```